# Angular nested component and reactive forms updating data model

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-reactive-forms

The problem is that after updating values in my form and then selecting the button to display the form again the values are sometimes there. 
I have tried to do this in different ways using a BehaviorSubject and also doing it with the EventEmitter. Any help would be appreciated.

I have attached the plunker: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/8UZS6ds0BaKoui7JpLJJ?p=preview)

Below is the data for my plunker example.

```
  this.units = [
  { 
    id: 1, 
    name: "Unit 1", 
    alarms: [
      { 
        name: "Alarm 1",
        description: ""
      },
      { 
        name: "Alarm 2",
        description: ""
      }
    ]
  },
  { 
    id: 2, 
    name: "Unit 2", 
    alarms: [
      { 
        name: "Alarm 1",
        description: ""
      },
      { 
        name: "Alarm 2",
        description: ""
      },
      { 
        name: "Alarm 3",
        description: ""
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

The user selects Unit 1 button and updates the description property of the first Alarm.
The user clicks on the Unit 2 button and the data is save to the collection in the ngOnChange with the call to ***this.updateData(changedProp.previousValue);***
When the user click on button Unit 1 the value changed in the description of the first alarm is not always there.

I am also not sure if there is a better way of doing this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have a github link to the one I tried with the BehaviorSubject: https://github.com/GertB1/test-forms

Comment: using previous value isn't good idea to save the unit

Comment: Hi Yerkon. I am using the previous value to get the id of the unit that I want to update. Then I use the form to extract the values that changed.

Comment: If I add a save button and remove the this.updateData(changedProp.previousValue); from the ngOnChanges then it works as expected. Is there a way to save automatically with out the save button? I am not sure if there is a life cycle hook that I can use?

Comment: I can solve your problem, but later✌

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get access to child `UnitEdit` component from parent and when select the `tab`, call `this.unitComp.updateData(unit)` method from parent to save unit state:

```
export class App {
  units: Unit[];
  unit: Unit = null;
  constructor(private unitService: UnitService) {
  }

    @ViewChild(UnitEditComponent)
  private unitComp: UnitEditComponent;

  ...

  unitSelected(unit: Unit) {
    this.unitComp.updateData(this.unit);
    // save unit states
    console.log(this.unitComp)
    this.unit = unit;
  }
}
```

If you need more detail about `@ViewChild` decorator look at [Parent calls an @ViewChild()](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-calls-an-viewchild)

[Plunker EXAMPLE](https://plnkr.co/edit/LNecXVU29c5pxGLM1Xzw?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks Yerkon you are for-sure a master.